# Issue with a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, web

Does anyone know why is this thingy showing up on top of our wordpress website, on every single page that you enter - http://sportsabac.org.rs/. Could it be the theme itself that is problematic..? I mean, when I change it - "Twenty eleven" is called, the problem goes away...

Answer (score 0):

The class should be define within tag braces but your class difine outside like
your tag is 
class="home blog custom-background single-author two-column right-sidebar">
it should be in

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is closed html tag `>` just before this part of code.

Answer (score 0):

The class should define within tag braces,

Try this;

```
<div class="home blog custom-background single-author two-column right-sidebar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to try that, just as soon as I find out where is it located. This really ain't my thing, just trying my best to fix it.. >.<